# MagicSquare. Please check for my error

Tags: java

My assignment is on the MagicSquare, I have a few minor error I believe that I cannot figure out. It is to be a 3x3 magicsquare with random numbers 1-9.

Please do not change the methods for that what we are required to use.

So far what I have noticed:

On line 76, I call the method `magicSquare.magicSquare();` since it is to be reset, however when I run the program it crashes in the end. There are also more errors to this I believe. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        //Scanner part two

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //declare needed variables here
        String userIn = "";

        //this is the start menu
        while(!userIn.equals("start")) {
            System.out.println("Enter 'start' to begin the game.");
            userIn = input.next().toLowerCase();

            if (userIn.equals("start")) {
                    magicSquare.magicSquare();//ultimately starts the magic square method
            }
        }
    }

    //method
    public static void magicSquare() {  
        //initializes the magic square matrix array
        int [][] square = new int[3][3];

        square = resetMatrix(square);//this uses the resetMatrix method to set matrix to all 0
        square = fillMatrix(square);//this uses the fillMatrix method to set the matrix to unique numbers 1-9
        magicSquare.displayMagicSquare(square); //this prints the matrix for user to see
        System.out.println("Rows sum: " +sumRows(square)); //this displays rows sum
        System.out.println("Columns sum: " +sumColumns(square)); //this displays columns sum
        System.out.println("Diagonals sum: " +sumDiagonals(square)); //this displays diagonl sums

        //decides if square is magic using isMagicSquare method
        if (isMagicSquare(square) == true) {

            System.out.println("Matrix is a Magic Square!");

        }
        else if (isMagicSquare(square) == false) {

            System.out.println("Matrix is not a Magic Square. \n");
            resetMatrix(square);// this resets matrix and restarts to find a magic square

            magicSquare.magicSquare();
        }
    }

    //this method to fill matrix with numbers
    public static int[][] fillMatrix(int [][] array) {
        //this loops through each element and uses isUnique method to set random and unique values.
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                int num = 0;
                while (isUnique(array, num) == false) {
                    num = (int)(9.0 * Math.random()) + 1;
                }
                array[i][j] = num;
            }
        }
        return array; 
    }

    //this used to reset the matrix by setting each array element to 0
    public static int[][] resetMatrix(int [][] array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                array[i][j] = 0; //this loops through each element in the array and sets them to 0
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static void displayMagicSquare(int[][] array) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                  System.out.print(array[i][j] +"   ");//Prints each row for the array
            }
            System.out.println(" ");// this goes to next row (blank)
        }
    }
    /*
     * LOOK HERE
     * EDIT: SumRows () and SumColumns is wrong
     */
    //this is used to calculate the sums of the rows
    public static int sumRows(int [][]array) {// sum of rows and sum of columns is wrong
        int sum = 0;
        int r1=0,r2=0,r3=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j =0; j< 3; j++) {
                sum += array[i][j];
            }
            if (i==0)
                 r1=sum;//assigns 1st row sum to r1
                if (i==1)
                 r2=sum;//assigns 2nd row sum to r2
                if (i==2)
                 r3=sum;//assigns 3rd row sum to r3
            }
        if (r1==r2&&r2==r3) {//if all rows are equal

            return r1;//return the number (it should be 15)
        }
        else {
            return -1;//returns -1 if row sums are not equal
        }
    }

    /*
     * Fix me
     */

    //this is initially used to calculate the sums of the columns
    public static int sumColumns(int [][]array) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                sum += array[i][j];
            }       
        }
        if (sum/3 !=15) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return sum/3;
        }
    }

    //this is initially used to calculate the sums of the diagonals
    public static int sumDiagonals(int [][] array) {

        int diagSum1 = array[0][0] + array[1][1] + array[2][2];
        int diagSum2 = array[0][2] + array[1][1] + array[2][0];

        if ((diagSum1 == 15) && (diagSum2 == 15)) {
            return 15;
        }
        else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    //This boolean method goes through the matrix and checks if the value is unique.
    public static boolean isUnique(int [][] array, int num) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] == num) {
                    //Check whether IF  an element is equal to the number assigned it 
                    //IT returns false requiring the variable to be changed!
                    return false; 

                }
            }
        }
        return true;        
    }

    public static boolean isMagicSquare(int [][] array) {

        //as a result, this fundamentally checks if the matrix/array is a MagicSquare
        if ((+sumRows(array) == 15) && (+sumColumns(array) == 15) && (+sumDiagonals(array) == 15)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please copy and paste (*not* as an image!) the text of the error or stack trace you are seeing, and how exactly you are getting this error. As it is, it is difficult to know where to start looking for your problem.

Comment: So I also attempted to fix my sumColumns method but I messed up greatly, so more errors, but 

"1   9   7    
2   6   8    
4   3   5    
Rows sum: -1
Columns sum: -1
Diagonals sum: -1
Matrix is not a Magic Square. 

6   7   4    
3   9   2    
1   5   8    
Rows sum: -1
Columns sum: -1
Diagonals sum: -1
Matrix is not a Magic Square. 

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at magicSquare.magicSquare(magicSquare.java:61)
 at magicSquare.magicSquare(magicSquare.java:77)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I fixed almost everything except for the recursion occurring.

It's at this part:

```
if (isMagicSquare(square) == true) {

    System.out.println("Matrix is a Magic Square!");
}
else if (isMagicSquare(square) == false) {

    System.out.println("Matrix is not a Magic Square. \n");
    resetMatrix(square); // this resets matrix and restarts to find a magic square

    magicSquare.magicSquare();
}
```

The `magicSquare.magicSquare();` is causing limited lines of the same error but the program is working fine? Help.